# Multiple kentico sites, direct url to CSS for one site is requiring a login

Tags: html, css, kentico, membership

I have a kentico install with multiple sites, all 'should' be set up the same but having a weird issue with the 3rd site i just launched.  Any sort of file (image, script, or css) won't load by its relative path, and if i try to open the url i am presented with a kentico login screen.

The truly weird part is if i put the same url path but put one of the other sites domains in front of it, the image loads fine.

```
newsite.com/imageURL <- wont load
othersite.com/imageURL <- loads
otheroldsite.com/imageURL <- loads
```

hopefully that makes sense, i've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: Are there permissions set on that site to require a login?  Are the files located in the media library or are they located in the file system (manually placed there)? Do you have any IIS rewrites in place overwriting the URL at all?

Answer (score 0):

Start with CSS first, make sure you've enabled the css for your new site:

```
 CSS stylesheets\YourCSSName\Sites
```

For the media library you must have permissions

```
Media libraries\YourMediaLibraryName\Security
```

Make sure that 'See library Content' is set for All Users

But scripts usually in ~/CMSScripts/Custom/ so any site in you case should be able to access them. If your script is there and you can't load it -  it's not Kentico permission issue.

Comment: Having those files those folders is a great practice but won't break anything if you're using them on a different site.  For instance if I want to use /cmsscripts/custom/domain1/jquery.js on domain2.com it will work just fine because you are not limiting access within Kentico (it would have to be on IIS side).  Same is true with media library files.  I could link to your images on your site from my site as long as the permissions were set on the media library (hence my question to the OP).